# Trouble with CSS 'overflow' property

Tags: html, css, properties, overflow

I have the following HTML / CSS:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <pre>
                    <code>
This is a test!
This is a very long line that is designed to exceed the length of the visible area of the page. This is a very long line that is designed to exceed the length of the visible area of the page.
                    </code>
                </pre>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As expected, the second line of content exceeds the visible area of the page. However, I do not want this to happen, so I've modified the `<code>` line to look like this:

```
<code style="overflow: hidden;">
```

However, the content still exceeds the visible page length. I simply want the text truncated. I have tried moving `overflow: hidden` to other tags, but still no luck.

Here is the example on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/yYGRP/) where you can see it in action and play around with it.

---

**Note:** I need to have the `<pre>` be the exact width of the page (in the example above, assume the table is the width of the page).

**Edit:** the extra tags are there because I have omitted some other code that doesn't apply - and without the table, the problem doesn't manifest itself

Comment: Overflow requires a defined width/height.

Comment: @Steve: Can I use a relative width?

Comment: @George - As far as I know, yes.  The `div` just needs something to indicate when overflow is occurring.  If there's no explicit "edge", then the element will just keep resizing automatically.

Comment: @Steve: It doesn't seem to... see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yYGRP/17/).

Comment: I think I found a rather complicated solution. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/yYGRP/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is give the `<div>` tag a `width` attribute.  Then you'll be set.

```
<div style="width:200px; overflow:hidden;">
    <pre>
        <code>This is a test!
            This is a very long line that is designed to exceed the length of the visible area of the page.  This is a very long line that is designed to exceed the length of the visible area of the page. 
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Oh... and do away with the table.

[HERE IS YOUR UPDATED JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yYGRP/16/)

## EDIT:

If  you need to have the width the exact same width as the page, you can do some JavaScript magic to get the innerWidth

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm

So you simply set the `<div>` width to the `innerWidth` of the page.  Then all of the content inside the Div will be the appropriate width for you.

Comment: +1 for being helpful... unfortunately, I need the `<pre>` to be the exact width of the page, which may vary.

Comment: Thanks! This is the closest it looks like I'll get to what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 4):

```
div {
   width: 300px; /* or pick a width */
  overflow: hidden;  ​
}
```

does the trick.

But I have to say, what an odd amalgam of markup. For one thing, why do you even need the table?

Comment: I need it because I'm intentionally omitting some of the other code that doesn't apply.

Comment: is it tabular data? if it's layout in any way, you can do away with tables completely. Tables should only be used for tabular data... you know... the crap that looks like spreadsheets.

Comment: @rock: No, it's part of something else. (Not tabular data, but something that DIVs cannot be used for.)

Answer (score 1):

You shall wrap your `pre` and `code` tags inside a `div` tag, since div tags more easily handles the ovreflow property. and you'll also need to specify the `width` and `height` of div, because `overflow` property does not work without width and height.

> ```
> <table>
> <tr>
>     <td>
>         <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 200px; height: 200px">
>             <pre>
>                 <code>
> This is a test!
> This is a very long line that is designed to exceed the length of the visible area of the page. This is a very long line that is designed to exceed the length of the visible area of the page. 
>                </code>
>             </pre>
>         </div>
>     </td>
> </tr>
> </table>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
display:block;
width:200px;
overflow:hidden
```

if you don't want to use div.

Comment: please format your code blocks properly so that they make more sense.